# How to calculate the chances of getting the lead in a coin toss-game if you are already behind?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

So for example you are a fair coin toss game of 100 and after 70 turns you are losing be 32-38.

What are the chances you will find yourself in the lead at any given moment? So not just the chances that you will win, but the chance that you at one point will be in the lead?

Comment: sounds very similar to [Bertrand’s ballot problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem): you need to count the paths/strings that match your condition; the various methods illustrated in the link can be helpful here as well.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, the Bertrand's problem is the chance of always being ahead while, of course, you also have the chance that you win in the end. Whereas mine is different from both. I ended up calculating a few paths by hand and then coding it.

Comment: We can model the lead as a symmetric $1-$D random walk starting at $X = 6$, and ask for the probability that the first passage time to $-1$ is more than $30$.  Are you familiar with random walks or generating functions, if so this can be computed.

Comment: it is not as different as you think - for you to **never** get the lead is the same as your opponent **always** staying ahead (or even); the complication is that you have to sum over several possible final scores, but it can be done.

Comment: @NickPavlov when you phrase it like that it become obvious indeed, thanks. As said, I coded it and it found answers that were satisfying. Thanks for the explanation and response :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can show that the probability of at some point being ahead, but not winning, is the same as the probability of winning; clearly then, since winning also implies being ahead at some point, $P(A) = 2P(W)$, where $A$ is "ahead at some point" and $W$ is "win."

It goes like this. For $P(W)$, we count the paths starting at $-6$ and ending at a positive value, anything from $\{2, 4, \dots, 24\}$. Now for $P(A\cap W^c)$, consider the paths that start at $-6$, are at some point positive, but end up at non-positive values. By reflecting (across $+1$) the last section from the last moment of being ahead (exactly at $+1$) to the endpoint, we find a one-to-one correspondence with paths starting at $-6$ and ending at reflections of the endpoints, which happen to be exactly the same positive endpoints we used to count the winning paths. So the count is the same. For probabilities, just divide by the total number of paths and you get
$$ P(W) = P(A\cap W^c) = {\rm binomcdf}(11; 30, 0.5) $$

---

Note that if the total number of coin flips in the game was odd, it is a little different. But simply by adding one extra flip after the end of the game, you can still apply the same idea to find $P(A_n) = P(A_{n+1}) = 2P(W_{n+1})$, where a subscript $n$ on the events stands for "... in the $n$-flip game". The second equality holds in light of the discussion above for an even-flip game, while the first holds because the first moment you get ahead can only happen on an odd flip, so if the last flip is even, it changes nothing in terms of having been ahead.

Comment: "I can show that the probability of at some point being ahead, but not winning, is the same as the probability of winning" 
- Great stuff, I can see that as well now! The coding I did was with random input and is consistently around the same value as your exact binomcdf :-)